# WebApi, append class with controller naming convention

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webforms

Using web Forms, In order to correctly call a webAPI controller, the controller must be appended with `Controller`. IS there a way that I can break this convention and Append it with whatever I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filip has a cool blog post demonstrating how to do this:

http://www.strathweb.com/2013/02/but-i-dont-want-to-call-web-api-controllers-controller/